# How to combine two arrays with different index values while using return array function?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `return array` function to return multiple query results in PHP. The function I used  is: `$main_ar=return array($query_result1,$query_result2)`. It is giving me two arrays at once like below:

```
Array ( [word_id] => 3 [main_word] => happy [n1] => Jason [v1] => plays [n2] => football  ) 
Array ( [word_id] => 4 [main_word] => dog [n1] => Carter  [v1] => plays [n2] => fetch_ball )
```

Now I want to combine these two array so that `n1` index of first array can be printed with other indexes of second array. As a result I can get `Jason dog` `Jason Carter` `Jason plays` `Jason fetch_ball` etc. But using foreach loop is not helping me in here. It is giving 2 index values at the same time:

```
foreach ($main_ar as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $last) {
        echo $last['n1'];
    }
}
```

Output is: `JasnCarter`. 
What's the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `n1` from the first array and loop the second one.

```
<?php 
$first=$array[0]['n1'];
foreach( $array[1] as $key=>$value ){ 

   //skip word_id
   if($key == 'word_id')continue; 

   echo $first.' '.$value;
  }
```